# QT Gui Window appears then disappears in Maya

Tags: python, pyside, maya

Two issues here.  I am not understanding how to get my GUI code to work as a Maya shelf button as opposed to running in the script editor. My first issue is whether there is any easy way to call my code in the if --main-- portion?  Right now I am having to throw the few lines I have there into it's own function and call that way.  Here is what I have:

```
from PySide import QtCore, QtGui, QtUiTools
import maya.cmds as cmds

try:
    _fromUtf8 = QtCore.QString.fromUtf8
except AttributeError:
    def _fromUtf8(s):
        return s

try:
    _encoding = QtGui.QApplication.UnicodeUTF8
    def _translate(context, text, disambig):
        return QtGui.QApplication.translate(context, text, disambig, _encoding)
except AttributeError:
    def _translate(context, text, disambig):
        return QtGui.QApplication.translate(context, text, disambig)

class Ui_Dialog(object):
    def setupUi(self, Dialog):
        Dialog.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("Dialog"))
        Dialog.resize(400, 300)

        GUI STUFF HERE


    def retranslateUi(self, Dialog):
        SET TEXT STUFF

    def closeBtn_clicked(self):
        DO SOMETHING

    def swapRefBtn_clicked(self):
        DO SOMETHING


if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys
    app = QtGui.QApplication.instance()
    if app is None:
        app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)       
    Dialog = QtGui.QDialog()
    ui = Ui_Dialog()
    ui.setupUi(Dialog)
    Dialog.show()
    app.exec_()
```

I am doing this as the shelf button, which obviously will not work (is there anyway to access the snippet in the if "--main--"?):

```
import swapRef as swap
swap.main()
```

The only fix I have found is throwing all of this into it's own function and then just calling it:

```
def main():
    import sys
    app = QtGui.QApplication.instance()
    if app is None:
        app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)       
    Dialog = QtGui.QDialog()
    ui = Ui_Dialog()
    ui.setupUi(Dialog)
    Dialog.show()
    app.exec_()
```

HOWEVER...issue #2 when I make this change, my GUI Window now pops open and quickly poofs/disappears.  I am not sure why throwing this code into a function and calling it would cause that change?  Please help, I've been sitting on this with no clue as to why.

Comment: Just to add, I've done some some research and the app.exec() should be holding the window.  Why does it not hold it when I move the if __main__ portion into it's own function and call it there, as opposed to it running fine when it is left as is?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't think you need to call `app.exec_()` if there was already an instance of the `QApplication` created by Maya. I suspect that probably that call does nothing in that case, which is why your function returns (which is good or else it would block the rest of maya).

Your issue with the dialog disappearing is then because you are not saving a reference to the `Dialog` variable and so it is garbage collected when the `main` function finishes. You should return `Dialog` from your function and store it somewhere permanent to prevent garbage collection. I suspect doing `dialog = swap.main()` will suffice (don't forget to add the `return Dialog` line too)

Comment: Thank you!  This sort of makes sense.  I wasn't returning the Dialog window.  Are you sure the app.exec isn't necessary?  It does work without it, I guess I am not understanding that since I thought that is what would hold the window for interaction.

Comment: @sz200 I think maya will have called `app.exec_()` itself. There is no reason for it to have created an instance of `QApplication` but not call `app.exec_()`